# I don't get why these two SQL queries with WHERE IN give different results

Tags: mysql

What I wanted to do
: **DELETE row only if there is a data exists that meets the WHERE condition.**

table looks like below and I'm using MySQL.

```
table A
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
|        id | user_id     | created_date        |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
|        17 | Amy         | 2021-04-19 17:00:00 |
|        19 | Amy         | 2021-04-20 17:00:00 |
|        20 | Amy         | 2021-04-22 17:00:00 |
|        21 | Bob         | 2021-04-22 17:00:00 |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

**1st try**
I tried below query, but it failed.
I wanted to delete only Amy's 2021-04-20 data, but it deleted all three Amy's rows.

```sql
DELETE FROM A
WHERE user_id IN (
  SELECT tmp.user_id from (SELECT user_id FROM A WHERE date(created_date)=date("2021-04-20") AND user_id="Amy") tmp )
AND user_id="Amy";
```

**2nd try**
succeeded.
Below query only deletes one row that meets the condition.

```sql
DELETE FROM A
WHERE created_date IN (
  SELECT tmp.created_date from (SELECT created_date FROM A WHERE date(created_date)=date("2021-04-20") AND user_id="Amy") tmp )
AND user_id="Amy";
```

#### question

I don't get why these two SQL queries give different results.
All I changed was just using another column.
Maybe I'm not fully understanding `IN` or subquery :(
Please give some advice.

Comment: The sub-select returns a value/values. In the first it returns "Amy". In the second it returns a date. Try selecting the values in the sub-select and then manually putting that value in the outer select. I'm sure you'll notice the difference  :) Consider if the SQL said `DELETE FROM A WHERE user_id IN ("Amy", "Bob")` as opposed to `DELETE FROM A WHERE date_created IN (date("2021-04-22"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what can help you understand this situation is to know the order of execution of an MySQL statement.

1. `FROM` clause
2. `WHERE` clause
3. `SELECT` clause
4. `GROUP BY` clause
5. `HAVING` clause
6. `ORDER BY` clause

So in this case the interpretation of your query starts FROM your original table. however the main query in its where condition has another query that also begins to be evaluated in that order. The conditional in the WHERE statement of the subquery where in the first case is:

```
SELECT tmp.user_id from (SELECT user_id FROM example WHERE date(created_date)=date("2021-04-20") AND user_id="Amy") tmp;
```

The result of that query is `'Amy'`. Because even though you evaluate with the createddate you are requesting the user_id in the SELECT statement.

In the second case:

```
SELECT tmp.created_date from (SELECT created_date FROM example WHERE date(created_date)=date("2021-04-20") AND user_id="Amy") tmp
```

The result is `'2021-04-20 17:00:00'` which is the result that effectively in your search you will eliminate a single record.

Continuing with the order of execution, we can already notice that in both cases the data universe changes because you are changing the search condition in your main query with the `WHERE user_id IN` or with the `WHERE created_date IN`.

In the first it is looking for everything it finds with the user_id `'Amy'` and in the second it is looking for everything with the date `'2021-04-20 17:00:00'`.

Only theoretically, if we wanted to solve the first case, you should also include in the main query the conditional of the date field, which is the field that can differentiate the 3 cases of 'Amy'. It would be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM example
WHERE user_id IN (
  SELECT tmp.user_id from (SELECT user_id FROM example WHERE date(created_date)=date("2021-04-20") AND user_id="Amy") tmp )
and created_date IN (SELECT tmp.created_date from (SELECT created_date FROM example WHERE date(created_date)=date("2021-04-20") AND user_id="Amy") tmp)
```

Regards.